# How to configure security algorithm on msal secured Web API using Azure AD?

Tags: .net, jwt, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-msal

I have already done app registrations in Azure AD for ASP.NET Core 6 Web API and Angular SPA. My angular SPA acquires token using MSAL - but I find the token signature uses hmac256.

Tasks left

1. I am bit unclear on the code required in the API `startup.cs`
2. How to mention a rsa signature, since token comes from `AcquireToken` in MSAL lib and not our own `CreateToken` method this time.

The previous developer had added a security requirement and used `AddAuthenticationScheme` in startup. I am not sure where `AddJwtBearer` and signing credentials (where security algorithm can be configured) fit into this setup. USUALLY `AddJwtBearer` is done as part of `AddAuthentication`.

## I'm seeking clarity.
update:

my actions following this question.

i mentioned the default scheme in addauthentication and added Addmicrosoftidentitywebapi (instead of addjwtbearer) after installing Microsoft.Identity.web since i was using Azure AD.Authorize in controller was emptied of arguments...the default scheme mentioned earlier is good enough. previously i think AddAzureAD was used for binding to Azure ad  this took care of signature error and everything was in sync.Easy to get lost in the info and samples of years ago involving b2c and what not. i did a similar task only 2 years ago and had to relearn everything. beware of changes every 2-3 years.just focusing on what i needed for azure ad did the job .

Answer (score 0):

In your API project, you should have codes below.

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "ClientId": "azure_ad_ap_id_which_is_assigned_api_permission",
  "ClientSecret": "client_secret_of_the_aad_app",
  "Domain": "tenant_id",
  "TenantId": "tenant_id", // A guid (Tenant ID = Directory ID) or 'common' or 'organizations' or 'consumers'
  "Audience": "api://app_id_of_the_aad_app_expsosing_the_api"
},
```

In program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "allowall",
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod();
                      });
});
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
...
...
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

And then `[Authorize]` attribute in controller.

When we use azure ad to protect our web api, we could follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scenario-protected-web-api-overview). This requires us to add authorization into the project which would validate the bearer token inside the Authorization request header automatically. And exposing a custom api within an Azure AD app is necessary, the app we exposing the api and the app used to assigned the exposing api could be the same one. In this scenario, both the SPA and the web api project could use the same aad app to configure the authentication and authorization.

In SPA, after we sign in the app with ms account, we use MSAL library to generate the access token, and we need to set the `scope`, we are now trying to generate an access token to call our custom API, so here we should set the scope with value that we exposed. Then inside the token, we could have `scp` claim which value should be like `api://aad_app_id_which_we_exposing_api/custom_api_permission_name`. Then in our API project, since we already add the authorization scheme, it would validate the api permission/audience/and some other claims then allow the request.

Comment: we have [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/sample-v2-code?tabs=apptype#web-api) in ms official documents.

Comment: hey thanks for your effort...initially i thought i had already looked at the sample....but i had to look closer n make those minor corrections that made it work...so it was an important lead when i didnt quite expect it.