# ASP.NET Core 6 & ReactJS Azure Authentication Integration

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm trying to get a ReactJS website to be able to communicate with web APIs set up around our estate.  We use Azure integrated SSO, and I'd like to be able to use that so that a user can sign on with a React front-end, then use that sign-on to request data from our web APIs.   I've been trying to get it to work, but I'm not able to get user details in the ASP.NET Core 6 controller action, but it doesn't seem to be there either in the User object, or in the Request's "access_token" property.

We're using "@azure/msal-react" in the React front-end to authenticate the user.  It works fine there - the user is able to log on via SSO and be recognised by the React app.

Using MSAL, I call MsGraph to get the user's details:

```
 instance.acquireTokenSilent({
        ...loginRequest,
        account: accounts[0]
      }).then((response) => {
        callMsGraph(response.accessToken).then(r => {
          const gData: GraphData = {
            givenName: r.givenName,
            surname: r.surname,
            userPrincipalName: r.userPrincipalName,
            id: r.id,
            accessToken: response.accessToken,
            authToken: r.authToken
          };
          props.setGraphData(gData);
        });
```

Having gotten the `accessToken`, I then call our Web API like this:

```
export async function getAvailableSites(accessToken: string) {
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_baseurl}/Controller/Action`;
    const headers = new Headers();
    const bearer = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;

        headers.append("Authorization", bearer);

    const options = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers
    };

    const result = await fetch(url, options);
    const jsonData = await result.json();
    return jsonData;
}
```

I've configured Authentication in ASP.NET like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
                    {
                        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            ValidateIssuer = true,
                            ValidateAudience = true,
                            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        };
                    })
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(AzureADConfig)
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(graphApiScopes)
        .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("GraphAPI"))
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

services.AddCors(o =>
            {
                o.AddPolicy("AllowReactJSPolicy", p =>
                {
                    p.WithOrigins("*");
                });
            });
```

The controller action is tagged with "Authorize", but there's nothing in the access_token property:

```
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Action()
    {
        var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
    }
```

The `User` object is also empty.

I can get the raw "Authorize" HTTP header, and get data out of it like this:

```
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
        {
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(token);
        }
```

But most of the data is encrypted. In any case - surely there's a better way of handling it than raw processing of HTTP headers, isn't there?

I really need to know who the user is, because it's a necessary parameter of one of the methods I do later. I'd also like to be sure that the user is being properly validated, and that ASP.NET Core isn't just letting every request through.

Without the ability to use SSO, React.js effectively useless to us.

Comment: To be clear, your code above is working? And you just want to know if there's a better way? Or you are expecting data in the access_token property and want to know why you aren't seeing any?

Answer (score 0):

We are now having a reactjs client app + asp.net core webapi backend app. So that we need to pass an access token to the api and we could get the secured API data response, right? By the way, we already called the graph api successfully in the react app and we are now just want the api controller to get the user profile we get from Graph API.

So firstly we need to know, [access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/access-token-claims-reference) doesn't contain claims to include the user data, and in this kind of scheme, the access token we used to call our own webapi is different from the access token we used to call Graph API. The most important difference is the `scope`. For example, scope for Graph api might look like `User.Read.All` but scope for custom webapi might look like `api://app_id/api_permission_name`.

What we should do first, is changing the configurations in the api project, the first we need to change is that we should use `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi` instead of `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp`. We have a tutorial here to guide us how to expose an API to use it to [protect your web api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scenario-protected-web-api-overview) and how to generate a correct access token to call this api. We have [official samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/sample-v2-code?tabs=apptype#web-api) here as well and I also had a test several days before, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77389274/14574199) the summary of the configurations inside the api project in my test.

After we set up the configurations in the api, we can now generate an access token with the scope we exposed and assigned to the authentication app. Now we are already able to connect the api and the client app, so that we could pass the user data in the request body, if we don't want to pass the data through the request, we are also able to call graph api inside the api project, However, we could use [on-behalf-of](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) flow inside the api project to use the access token to generate a new access token for calling graph API.

Here's my code snippet to do it.

```
StringValues authorizationToken;
HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out authorizationToken);
var token = authorizationToken.ToString().Replace("Bearer ","");
var scopes = new[] { "User.Read.All" };
var tenantId = "xxxx";
var clientId = "xxxx";
var clientSecret = "xxxx";
var onBehalfOfCredential = new OnBehalfOfCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, token);
var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(scopes);
var token2 = onBehalfOfCredential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext, new CancellationToken()).Result.Token;
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(onBehalfOfCredential, scopes);
var user = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync();
```